# KeyError: 'APP1' when reading metadata with exif

Tags: python, python-3.x, metadata, exif

I want to cycle through every jpg in my pictures folder and return the name and the date it was taken and add it to a list. Running my code however results in KeyError: APP1. Below you can see my code:

```
from exif import Image

path = 'F:/Bilder/'
bilder_list = []

for i in os.listdir(path):
     if ".jpg" in i:
          with open(path+i, 'rb') as image_file:
               image = Image(image_file)
          bilder_list.append(image.datetime)

print(bilder_list)
```

Any idea what went wrong here? Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Are there other files or folders in the Bilder directory? Maybe try substituting the if condition for `if i.endswith('jpg')`, it's a little bit more robust. Could it also be that not all your jpgs have exif data attached in them? You can use `image.has_exif` to test for that.

Comment: thank you, testing for image.has_exif solved my problem :)